# openmp on window xp doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, openmp

I have an application that runs on windows 7 without any problem. The application uses OpenMP and compiled by visual studio 2012.

When I try to run this application on a windows xp,  am getting error that it is not a windows 32 application.

If I disable OpenMP, it works well on windows XP.

How can I compile it to work on windows XP?

The application needs to work on windows 7 and 8 too.

Comment: Naive question but...did you carry [VC++ OpenMP DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h7x01y0.aspx) with you in Windows XP?

Comment: no! The error that I am getting is that it is not a win32 application. What DLL should I carry to windows xp?

Comment: You should always carry them (unless someone else installed that libraries before you). I added a link in the comment, basically vcomp110.dll

Comment: I copy it alongside of the application but it still doesn't work

Comment: Same architecture? (x86/AMD64?) I would check for stuff like that (assuming all libraries, including VC runtime, is properly installed)

Comment: I installed VC redistributable for VS 2012. I think that would be sufficient. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes (plus OpenMP DLL). That said another navie check would be to be sure if you compiled for same architecture (32 bit vs 64 bit).

Comment: Did you try building your application and all dlls with the v110_xp toolset?

Comment: I don't have any openmp.dll on my windows. Where are they?

Comment: @drescherjm: No, where can I find information on this subject?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx

Comment: @mans I posted link on my first comment.